# Missing argument 1 for Lib?

Tags: php, laravel

My website get error when accessing:

> Missing argument 1 for Lib\Repository\Data\TmdbData::getPartTrailer(), called in /home/*/app/lib/Repository/Data/TmdbData.php on line 2258 and defined

This is a part code in TmdbData.php

```
 public function getPartnumber()
 {
    if ( ! $this->partnumber) return '';

    return $this->partnumber;
 }

 public function getPartTrailer($parttrailer)
 {
    if ( ! $this->partnumber) return '';

    return $this->partnumber; 
 }
```

**And this is line 2258:**

```
    'partnumber' => $this->getPartnumber(),

    'parttrailer' => $this->getPartTrailer());  // line 2258
```

How to fix it ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an argument to your function. Try:

```
'partnumber' => $this->getPartnumber(),

'parttrailer' => getPartTrailer($this);
```

Comment: Hi, it showed an error: Call to undefined function Lib\Repository\Data\getPartTrailer()
How to fix it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Either pass an argument to `getPartTrailer` method:

```
'parttrailer' => $this->getPartTrailer('someargumant');
```

Or you may make the argument optional using a default argument:

```
public function getPartTrailer($parttrailer = null)
{
    if ( ! $this->partnumber) return '';
    return $this->partnumber; 
}
```